# Android automation tests with Appium

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, appium

I want to launch some automated tests in my Android app using Appium.

I'm adding these dependencies in my gradle file:

```
compile 'io.appium:java-client:4.0.0'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
```

and creating an `Appium` class where I define my `AndroidDriver` setting up the `DesiredCapabilities`.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android Emulator");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());

driver = new AndroidDriver(urlConnection.getURL(), capabilities);
```

My first unit test is creating the driver first of all

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
    try {
        Appium.connectAppium();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void myTest() {
    if (Appium.getDriver() != null) {
        // Test
    }
}
```

First question...

> Must I always define the APK location even if the tests are in the same
>   Android project? Cannot I use just somehow the package name/activityName?

```
File app  = new File("D:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents\\Android\\android-project\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\app-debug.apk");
URL url = new URL ("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
```

Second question...

> When launching my unit test against Appium Desktop (Appium v1.6.4) and using Android Emulator I always get an error:

```
[ADB] Error: my.package/my.package.modules.startup.StartActivity or my.package.debug.modules.startup.StartActivity never started
at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow...
```